# Constraint checking that foreign key matches with column in same table as primary key

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I have the following SQL schemas.

```sql
-- name is primary key
Programs (name, abbr)

-- idnr is primary key
Students (idnr, name, login, program)
    program → Programs.name

-- name is primary key
Branches (name, program)
    program → Programs.program

-- student is primary key
StudentBranches(student, branch, program)
    student → Students.idnr
    (branch, program) → Branches.(name, program)
```

In my domain description I have a constraint that a student can only choose branches which are available within their own programs.

But as of right now, the `StudentBranches` schema allows for a student to take a branch from a program that differs from the one they are taking. This is not allowed.

I need to add a constraint to disallow this, how can I do that? My idea was to use an INSERT BEFORE trigger, but I couldn't manage to write something that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* create a (redundant) unique constraint as target for a foreign key */
ALTER TABLE students ADD UNIQUE (program, idnr);

/* create a (redundant) unique constraint as target for a foreign key */
ALTER TABLE branches ADD UNIQUE (program, name);

/* include "program" in both foreign keys,
   so that it must be the same in both referenced tables */
ALTER TABLE studentbranches
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (program, student) REFERENCES students (program, idnr),
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (program, branch) REFERENCES branches (program, name);
```

With these foreign keys, the value of `program` in `studentbranches` must be the same as in the related `student` and `branches` rows. Consequently, a student can only be related to a branch with the same `program`.